# A proof of Lebesgue's decomposition theorem

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, radon-nikodym

I'm trying to prove Lebesgue's decomposition theorem. I took the ideas for the existence part from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3493284/proof-of-lebesgue-decomposition-theorem-deducing-lambda-2-mu), and those for the uniqueness part from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1515155/proving-uniqueness-in-lebesgue-decomposition)

> **Lebesgue's decomposition theorem:** Let $\mu, \nu$ be $\sigma$-finite measures on a measurable space $(X, \Sigma)$. Then there exist a unique pair $(\nu_0, \nu_1)$ of $\sigma$-finite measures such that:
>
> - $\nu=\nu_0+\nu_1$,
> - $\nu_0 \ll \mu$, i.e., $\nu_0$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$,
> - $\nu_1 \perp \mu$, i.e., $\nu_1$ and $\mu$ are singular.

Could you check if my proof of the part $\color{blue}{\nu (A) = \nu (A \cap B)}$ is fine? Thank you so much!

**My attempt:**

1. Existence:

Let $\lambda = \mu + \nu$. Then $\lambda$ is $\sigma$-finite and $\mu \ll \lambda$. By [Radon–Nikodym theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4538795/a-proof-of-radon-nikodym-theorem), the Radon–Nikodym derivative $f:X \to [0, \infty)$ exists, i.e.,
$$
f = \frac{\mathrm d \mu}{\mathrm d \lambda}.
$$

Let $B := \{f = 0\} \in \Sigma$. We define non-negative measures $\nu_0, \nu_1$ by
$$
\nu_0 (A) := \nu(A \cap B^c) \quad \text{and} \quad \nu_1 (A) := \nu(A \cap B)  \quad \forall A \in \Sigma.
$$

Clearly, $\nu=\nu_0+\nu_1$. Because $B$ is a $\mu$-null set, we get $\nu_1 \perp \mu$. Let's prove that $\nu_0 \ll \mu$. Assume $A \in \Sigma$ such that $\mu(A) = 0$. Then
$$
0=\mu (A)  = \int_A f \mathrm d [\mu + \nu] = \int_A f \mathrm d \mu  + \int_A f \mathrm d \nu = \int_A f \mathrm d \nu.
$$

It follows that $f (x)=0$ for $\nu$-a.e. $x \in A$. We want to prove $\nu (A \cap B^c) = 0$. It suffices to prove $\color{blue}{\nu (A) = \nu (A \cap B)}$. This indeed true because
$$
\nu (A) = \nu (\{x \in A \mid f(x) = 0\}) = \nu (\{x \in A \mid x \in B\})  = \nu (A \cap B).
$$

2. Uniqueness:

Let $(\lambda_0, \lambda_1)$ be another pair that satisfies the required properties. Then
$$
\nu_0 - \lambda_0 =  \lambda_1 - \nu_1.
$$

Because $\mu \perp \nu_1$, there is $\Omega_1 \in \Sigma$ with the following properties

- $\mu (A) = 0$ for all $A \in \Sigma$ such that $A \subset \Omega_1$.
- $\nu_1 (A) = 0$ for all $A \in \Sigma$ such that $A \subset \Omega_1^c$.

Because $\mu \perp \lambda_1$, there is $\Omega_2 \in \Sigma$ with the following properties

- $\mu (A) = 0$ for all $A \in \Sigma$ such that $A \subset \Omega_2$.
- $\lambda_1 (A) = 0$ for all $A \in \Sigma$ such that $A \subset \Omega_2^c$.

Clearly, $\nu_0 - \lambda_0 \ll \mu$. Let's prove that $\lambda_1 - \nu_1 \perp \mu$. Let $\Omega := \Omega_1 \cup \Omega_2$. Then

- $\mu (A) = 0$ for all $A \in \Sigma$ such that $A \subset \Omega$. This is because $\mu (\Omega) \le \mu (\Omega_1) + \mu (\Omega_2) = 0$.
- $(\lambda_1 - \nu_1) (A) = 0$ for all $A \in \Sigma$ such that $A \subset \Omega^c$. This is because $(\lambda_1 - \nu_1) (A) = \lambda_1 (A) - \nu_1 (A)=0$.

We have
$$
\begin{align}
(\nu_0 - \lambda_0) (A) &= (\nu_0 - \lambda_0) (A \cap \Omega) +  (\nu_0 - \lambda_0) (A \cap \Omega^c) \\
&= (\nu_0 - \lambda_0) (A \cap \Omega) +  (\lambda_1 - \nu_1) (A \cap \Omega^c)  \\
&=0+0\\
&=0.
\end{align}
$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: It might be worth checking ‘official’ proofs and comparing

Comment: This looks like the standard approach. One way to obtain the density $f = \frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}$ is to use the Riesz representation theorem.